# Reorganize list/tuple structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

In an exercise I am asked to reorganzie a tuple. Given the tuple: `temp = ( ("mandag", 16.0), ("tirsdag", 13.0), ("onsdag", 14.0), ("torsdag", 13.0), ("fredag", 15.0), ("lørdag", 13.0), )`

I am supposed to write a function called `data_reorganize` which outputs the following tuple when printed:

```
(('mandag', 'tirsdag', 'onsdag', 'torsdag', 'fredag', 'lørdag'),(16.0, 13.0, 14.0, 13.0, 15.0, 13.0))
```

I have managed this, but my code seems too long and chunky:

```
def data_reorganize(a):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in a:
        x.append(i[1])
    x = tuple(x)
    for i in a:
        y.append(i[0])
    y = tuple(y)
    return y,x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with `zip` and the `*` unpacking operator. Best part about this approach is that its reversible. Use this again on the output to get back the initial input! -

```
output = tuple(zip(*temp))
output
```

```
(('mandag', 'tirsdag', 'onsdag', 'torsdag', 'fredag', 'lørdag'),
 (16.0, 13.0, 14.0, 13.0, 15.0, 13.0))
```

---

Writing it as a function as you have mentioned in the question requirement -

```
def data_reorganize(temp: tuple):
    return tuple(zip(*temp))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code might be ameliorated as follows

```
def data_reorganize(a):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in a:
        x.append(i[1])
        y.append(i[0])
    return tuple(y), tuple(x)
```

Explanation: I integrated two separate `for i in a` into single and moved conversion to desired datatype into `return`.